# How to go back from fragment to activity with toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin

In MainActivity with menu I open FavoriteFragment, i want to go back with toolbar **`setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()`**

in fun `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
 R.id.favorite -> {
        fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val mainFragment: FavoriteFragment = FavoriteFragment().newInstance()
        fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, mainFragment)
            .addToBackStack("FAVORITE_FRAGMENT").commit()

        true
    }
```

and fun onBackPressed

```
    override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("FAVORITE_FRAGMENT") != null) {
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("FAVORITE_FRAGMENT", 0);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

In My fragment i create fun `showBackButton`:

```
fun showBackButton() {
    if (activity is MainActivity) {
        (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    }
}
```

Physical back button is work, but toolbar back isn't work

Comment: you only have to change your code little bit Like change this line `fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().replace()` with `fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().add()` and no need to override `onBackPressed()` I hope it will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet. (Sorry for java code, i dont know kotlin, you have to manually convert it)

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // ProjectsActivity is my 'home' activity
                super. onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));
    }
```